# AttributeError: 'CallbackQuery' object has no attribute 'chat'

Tags: python, telebot

Telebot, Python

При нажатии на кнопку "Билли Херрингтон" должна появляться картинка, но вместо этого ошибка.
В чём может быть проблема? Знатоки, помогите!
[image: Код][1]]

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])

Comment: `call.message.chat.id`

Answer (score 0):

Здраствуйте .
Проблема заключается в том , что call не имеет chat.

Вместо call.chat.id используйте это :

```
call.from_user.id
```

В итоге получается так :

```
bot.send_photo(call.from_user.id,photo=photo)
```